# What does IsEncrypted in local.appsettings.json of Azure function mean?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

The local.settings.json file for Azure function is created with the property IsEncrypted set to false.

```
{
   "IsEncrypted":false,
   "Values" : {
   }
}
```

What does this setting mean and how is it used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This setting represents whether the values in local.settings.json are encrypted using a local machine key. It's used with `func settings encrypt/decrypt/add` command of Azure Function Core Tools, hence manually change true/false is meaningless.

Usually we don't need to care about this setting and it's false by default. We can encrypt the settings file once we need to transfer it through internet and want to enforce the security. Because the file can only be decrypted at the machine where we encrypt it.

Here's the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file).

Comment: the default is not false. If the values are not encrypted then this should be set as false. 

It happened to me: the "IsEncrypted" property was removed, probably by VS code, and func start stopped working. It was a lot of brain power before I realized that was the reason because all i tried involved reverting back the repository version and local.settings.json is not git tracked. Microsoft just manages to add these kind of easter eggs (automagic of vscode to overwrite my local.settings.json) to make life exciting.

Comment: I wish they stuck with a single way to do things. We will be using the Azure `keyvault` on azure and `dot-net user-secrets` in dev environments. Since it's available for any application not just Azure Functions. Not a huge deal, just confusing.